# android json parsing a single element

Tags: android, json

My JSON response was that {"success":"1"}. I want to check this value and display Toast depend on these.if the success is 1, I want to display "login sucess" and success is "0", I want to display "error" in toast.I'm using volley library.

Comment: int result=jsonobj.getInt("success");  result==1 true else false

Comment: use JSON class object to get value of JSON response

Answer (score 2):

use JSON class object to get value of JSON response.

```
JSONObject jData=new JSONObject("YOUR JSON RESPONSE"); 

if(jData.getString("success").equals("1"))
   Toast.makeToast...()
else
   Toast.makeToast...()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this

```
 String result=response.getString("success");
    if(result.equals("0")){

    }
    if(result.equals("1")){

    }
```